# How do you implement 1.day.ago in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, helper

As you guys might have already guessed it, it's an interview question. But I'm not gonna disclose which company. I was asked to implement

```
1.day.ago
```

in Ruby. This is a date helper in Rails but this functionality doesn't exist in Ruby.

Comment: Look at the Rails source?  https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=ago

Comment: I think the only sensible answer is that only a fool would write their own time handling methods so pull in all or part of ActiveSupport. Date and time handling is ridiculously difficult to get right (leap years, leap seconds, DST, calendar switches, ...) so you should leave it up to the experts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All it does* is return the number of seconds in a day, multiplied by self:

```
class Fixnum
  def day
    self * (60 * 60 * 24) # seconds * minutes * hours
  end
end


# 10.days => 'self' is 10, so 10 * 60 * 60 * 24
```

Then, `.ago` subtracts that many seconds from `Time.now`:

```
class Fixnum
  def ago
    Time.now - self
  end
end

# 10.days.ago == Time.now - (10 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

<sup>*This is actually *not* all it does; in reality it returns a proxy object which represents the given duration. The math is also significantly more complex</sup>

Comment: he can alias day to days if he wants days

Comment: @bjhaid He could also add "minutes" or "years" but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Reality is not this simple. One day is not always 86400 seconds, hence all the ActiveSupport::Duration stuff inside the real version.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm pretty sure they'd be very satisfied with this answer on an interview question.

Comment: That's incredibly clever and simple

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Time.now-86400
#=> 2014-01-26 16:54:07 -0500
```

`86400` is the number of seconds in a day.

**Disclaimer:** This example obviously does not include shifts in time due to daylight savings. (Use at your own peril.)

Comment: The number of seconds in a day is not always 86400. Not even if you ignore DST issues.

Comment: @muistooshort that comment just blew my mind, please elaborate? Are you talking time travel?

Comment: The number of seconds in a minute is not always 60 either. [Leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: @muistooshort any good with algorithms? How likely would the event of a leap second corrupt the above operation in to returning an invalid value? This is something that is actually accounted for in ActiveSupport::Duration?

Comment: ActiveSupport's stuff, AFAIK, keeps track of what units it is working with so a day is a day rather than a certain number of seconds, then it punts down to the core libraries for the heavy lifting. A 1s mistake can turn into a whole day if that second is in the right place. The real point is that it is foolish to try to write your own time handling routines.